# How to call a javascript function in jsPLumb.ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsplumb

I want to call a javascript function that is is jsPlumb.ready(). I know that I can define jQuery functions inside jsPlumb, but my elements are dynamically created, so it won't work with jQuery.

my HTML code (the function should pass 2 values) :

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="fun(this, event)" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left: 120px;"></span>
```

I have explored the following options:

1. I know that you can use window.fun = function(){}; to create a global function, but how can I pass a parameter to it from my html.

   ```
   jsPlumb.ready(function() {
     window.fun = function(){  
       alert('fun');  
     }  
   });
   ```
2. Can I have a function defined in jsPlumb.ready() and call it? - I tried with this code, but the function was not called.

   ```
   jsPlumb.ready(function() {
     function fun(){  
       alert('fun');  
     }  
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsPlumbToolkit.ready(function () {
       $(document).on('click', '#your_id', function(event) {
           //may it will be work
       });
});
```

Comment: My html elements are dynamically created, so I cannot use jQuery. Thank you for your comment anyways.